# Pointer Arithmetic on pointers to pointers and the like

Tags: pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Is to well defined to use pointer arithmetic on pointers to pointers?
 eg

```
int a=some_value;
int* p=&a;
int**p2=&p;
```

Now would it be well defined behavior to perform arithmetic on p2?(eg p2+1, p2+2,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!

```
p + n
```

where `p` is a pointer and `n` is an integer is always well-defined.  It produces the address which is "n times the size of the element type p points to" bytes from `p` itself.  In this case `p2` is a pointer to a pointer.  So `p2 + 4` is the address "4 * the-size-of-pointers" bytes past `p2`.

Since you are pointing to local variables in your specific example, it would be odd.  But it will not be illegal.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is completely wrong:

```
int *p = &a;
```

declares a **single** pointer variable (not a array of pointers). This is equivalent, WRT indexing, with an array with a single element:

```
int *(array[1]) = { &a };
```

so you can do `(&array[0]) + 1` or `array + 1`, or `p + 1`, because forming a one-past-the-end pointer is allowed: a one-past-the-end pointer points to an imaginary element that's just after the end of the array. The one-past-the-end pointer is **not** dereferenceable, because it points to no real object.

But **you cannot compute any other pointer value**.

In particular, `p+2` is *not* valid.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by completely wrong.  The other answer never claimed that p was defined to be an array of pointers.  In fact the word "array" never appeared.  Regardless, the semantics of `p + n` is well-defined for pointer `p` and integer `n`.  Sure the operation may segfault, but that has nothing to do with the question.  And again, the question and the other answer never mentioned arrays at all.

Comment: "_In fact the word "array" never appeared._" That's the reason it is wrong: if there is no array, there is no "well-defined" pointer arithmetic. **Pointer arithmetic is defined on arrays.**

Comment: My guess is that we disagree on the meaning of well-defined.  The [C Reference manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/cman.pdf) says in Section 6.4, "Integers and pointers may be added" and section 7.4.1 explains what happens.  The C reference manual does NOT mention arrays either.  It simply says you get whatever data happens to be in memory at the computed address.  To me, the manual specifies a **well-defined** operation without ever mentioning the word array.  So our disagreement is based on the term well-defined which we are interpreting differently. Cheers. :)

Comment: @Ray guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341646/pointer-arithmetic-in-c-and-array-bounds should help...

Comment: Great link, @zuselegacy.  The _result_ of `p+2` is certainly undefined, even though the _behavior_ (i.e. adding the address to the number of bytes times sizeof(int)) is well defined.

Comment: @RayToal The behaviour is undefined, without any doubt.