# Memory protection in C

Tags: c, memory

Is there no memory protection in C ?
Can a process edit any memory space ?
how does C determines a memory is allocated is it stored somewhere ?
For instance :

```
int a[2] = {2,3};
int *ptrA = &a;

int b = 10;
int *ptrB = &b;

printf("%d ",*(ptrA+1009));
*(ptrA+1009) = 10;
printf("%d \n",*(ptrA+1009));

printf("%d ",*(ptrB+1009));
*(ptrB+1009) = 10;
printf("%d\n",*(ptrB+1009));
```

Here pointer to unallocated memory has read/write access. Snippet complies and runs with a warning.
Is it undefined behaviour/machine dependent ?

Comment: no protection. It is in fact Undefined behaviour, so be ware of the fire breathing dragons and trolls with wooden clubs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer arithmetic in c and array bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341646/pointer-arithmetic-in-c-and-array-bounds)

Comment: Undefined behavior.  However, if you run on Windows, you may trip the "0xC0000005 access violation error", but again, it isn't a certainty.

Comment: Yes we have no memory protection. The same is true in C++, although it is a different language - please do not tag C questions as C++. (There are advantages to this lack of protection - better performance for valid programs.)

Comment: `int *ptrA = &a;` is wrong because `a` is already a pointer to the first element. What you want is `int* ptrA = a;` or `int** ptrA = &a;`.

Comment: @HelloWorld how come?

Comment: @AlanStokes, yes.  I think I misunderstood HelloWorld's point.  The OP's code is not type-correct, as he said, and I deleted my previous comment.  Nevertheless, that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: That's why it's just a comment :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The names for these topics are `pointer arithmetic` and `array-to-pointer conversion`. See `§4.3` in c++ standard. When `int a[2]` is given, `a` is an array of ints. When you write `int* tmp = a` then `a` can be converted to a pointer that points to the first element of the array. If you write `&a` you still get the address of the array because of the mentioned paragraph but compilers like msvc don't compile this and they will tell you that `int(*)[2]` cannot be converted to `int*`.

Comment: @HelloWorld right. I kind of missed that a is an array already.  My bad.

Comment: "Can a process edit any memory space" - this is controlled by the operating system. In MS-DOS, a process could indeed edit any memory space.

Comment: @HelloWorld Clang and GCC have no issue with `int* p = &a`, and their interpretation generally matches the semantics I expect (`a` and `&a` are equivalent).  Is it wrong, or just interpreted differently in MSVC (e.g. convert to pointer first)?

Comment: Keep in mind, that the initial question asked for C++. gcc/clang raise a warning if compiled in [C](http://goo.gl/Rt6YHC) and the corresponding warning option is set. gcc/clang raise an error in [C++](http://goo.gl/B3fOy5) by default. The [C FAQ 6.13](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html) also covers this issue. `How do I declare a pointer to an array?` `Usually, you don't want to. When people speak casually of a pointer to an array, they usually mean a pointer to its first element.`

Comment: @M.M, you are right that whether a *process* can edit any memory space is determined by the OS.  If the question were whether a C program can do so, however, then the answer is that C does not define any way for a program to modify memory other than that of objects belonging to the program.

Comment: @HelloWorld Clang (3.6) and GCC (4.9.2) apparently treat `&a` as a valid pointer with an address of the first element, but still treat it as an invalid typed pointer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Memory protection* doesn't mean what you think it means: It's measures to stop a process from accessing memory it shouldn't access. However, processes of course can access their own memory, which C/C++ and a lot of other languages let you do.

> Here pointer to unallocated memory has read/write access.

dereferencing a pointer into unallocated is what we call a bug in your software :) However, it's totally OK that your compiler lets you do that. C/C++ *don't have your back*, if you want to juggle with pointers, by all means, do. You will provoke undefined behaviour or segmentation faults, if the addresses you try to access are not mapped in your process' memory (that's *memory protection* at work), but these languages let you do that.

Comment: Attempting to form a pointer to unallocated space also causes UB, even if not dereferenced, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341646/pointer-arithmetic-in-c-and-array-bounds)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built-in memory protection in C, but using a pointer to access memory outside the object to which it points -- as your code does -- invokes undefined behavior.  "Undefined behavior" does not mean that the program must fail or emit any particular diagnostic.  Those are permissible results, but if they were required then that would be *defined* behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The C/C++ standards don't have any requirements for dereferencing addresses.  They provide access to raw memory so are general enough to be valid on bare metal, virtual memory systems, etc...  So, as far as the language is concerned, it is perfectly valid to access a variable through an offset of a pointer to another variable or any memory reference in general.  It is undefined behavior though, so the actual behavior generally depends on the runtime and/or operating system and/or hardware.

This compiler is free to add bounds checks to all memory references though.  However, the general benefit of C/C++ is raw access to memory.  Runtime bounds checking is generally too expensive to be practical for production use, but it is often used in debugging to find these types of errors.  For a good example of runtime bounds checking, see [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) or [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) address sanitizer.

Most compilers will provide basic static bounds check warnings though.  You can (*should*) generally turn them into errors using a switch like `-Werror`.  There are also various static analyzers that will identify potential and verifiable out of bounds accesses.

Comment: C++ and especially C *are* general enough to be implemented on pretty much any hardware, but they have specific and relatively strict rules on the permissible ways to use pointers.  Those specifically preclude even computing a pointer to random memory, much less dereferencing one.  What they do not do is inherently prevent you from attempting to do so anyway, or define what the result will be if you do.

Comment: It's *UB*, but it isn't forbidden by the language.  It strictly doesn't preclude things like *FAM*s.  However, it's also why you should generally turn warnings into errors using `-Werror` or the relevant setting for your compiler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you explain where my answer is factually incorrect?

Comment: Your primary thesis is that "The C/C++ standards don't have any requirements for dereferencing addresses," but this is false.  C and C++ define the behavior for specific dereferences, and specify that all others exhibit undefined behavior.  You also say "as far as the language is concerned, it is perfectly valid to access a variable through an offset of a pointer to another variable or any memory reference in general," but this is patently false.  What you describe is *not* valid in any sense that is useful to someone trying to write C code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In the context of *memory protection*, *requirement for dereferncing* should be interpreted as regarding *invalid memory access*, which is a term that specifically is not defined in either language.  This is one of the reasons to better describe what your errors are to the compiler (e.g. your `-W`s or equivalents). The standards mark a lot of the behavior as undefined, which I clearly mention.  However, not all bounds or even *UB* can identified statically, which is why runtime checks are *necessary* to sanitize all potential errors (e.g. `valgrind`).

Comment: Whether you can present an interpretation of your answer that renders it an accurate statement is not much relevant.  As written, your answer is more likely to mislead people who don't already know the answer than it is to help them.  Factual correctness -- which I do not stipulate -- is not the standard here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I disagree.  I think the answer is more complex than the other answers suggest.